# Compute complex integral of $f(z)=(x^2 + y)+ i(xy)$, over $A=\lbrace t+it^2: 0 \leq t \leq 1 \rbrace.$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Let $f(z)=(x^2 + y)+ i(xy)$, $a=0$ and $b=1+i$. And let

$$A=\lbrace t+it^2: 0 \leq t \leq 1 \rbrace.$$

Prove

$$ \int_{A} f(z)= \frac{4}{15}+ i \frac{5}{4}$$.

And show

$$\int_{A} f(z) dz \neq \int_{B} f(z)dz,$$

where $B$ is the line segment joining the points $a$ and $b$.

We can see the set $A$ as a parametrized curve $\alpha(t)=t(1+i)$ for $t\in [0,1]$ and $B$ can be parametrized as the curve $\beta(t)=t(1+it)$. But seeing other complex integrals I cannot figure out how to integrate $\int_{A} f(z)$ and $\int_{B} f(z)$. Any guidance throught this will be aprecciated, the more explicit the better. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first integral is$$\int_0^1f(t+it^2)\times(1+2ti)\,\mathrm dt,$$whereas the second one is$$\int_0^1f(t+ti)\times(1+i)\,\mathrm dt.$$Can you take it from here?

Comment: Thanks! But from the  product $f(t+it^2)(1+2it)$ I got $[(2t^2-2t^3)+i(4t^2+t^3)]$ which integrating from $0$ to $1$ does not give me the requiered values :/ @José Carlos santos

Comment: I don't know how you did your computations, but I got $\frac4{15}+\frac54i$ and $\frac12+\frac76i$ respectively.

Comment: What I got was that$$f(t+it^2)\times(1+2ti)=-2 t^4+5 i t^3+2 t^2.$$

Comment: Note that $f(t+it^2)=2 t^2+i t^3$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for filling those details! Already understand your process, I aprecciate your time! Muito obrigado!

Comment: I'm glad I could help.